# how to get dynamic translations of mapped data with next-intl

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next-intl

I am new to nextjs and am having some troubles with i18n. I am using client side rendering and I get the basic concept of how the i18n and l10n work. However, now I have to provide translations for a card sections that I create when mapping over a data. And I am not sure how this dynamic translation works. I will provide my code:

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faDollarSign,
  faStar,
  faLocationDot,
  faChevronLeft,
  faChevronRight,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import apartmentData from "../apartmentData";

export default function CardSlider() {
  const [sliderRef, setSliderRef] = useState(null);

  const t = useTranslations("Popular Apartments");

  const sliderSettings = {
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1280,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },

      {
        breakpoint: 900,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const cards = apartmentData;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>{t("section title")}</h2>
          <div>
            <button onClick={sliderRef?.slickPrev}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} color="white" />
            </button>
            <button onClick={sliderRef?.slickNext}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} color="white" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Slider ref={setSliderRef} {...sliderSettings}>
          {cards.map((card, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${card.imageSrc})` }}></div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <h5>{card.title}</h5>
                  <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                    <span className="ml-2 font-bold">{card.rating}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} />
                    </div>
                    <div>{card.locationText}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faDollarSign}
                        className="h-3 w-6"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div>{card.pricingText}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>{card.description}</p>
              </div>
              <button>{t("btn")}</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For now, the card only shows data taken from apartmentData.js file but I need it translated to another language (bhs).

I have done the basic translation for `<h2>` and `<btn>`

```js
<h2>{t("section title")}</h2>
<button>{t("btn")}</button>
```

But I am stuck with the rest (card.title, card.rating, card.locationText, ard.pricingText and card.description) . Does anybody know how to do it?
I will also provide my bhs.json file in case it helps:

```json
  "Popular Apartments": {
    "section title": "Popularni Apartmani",
    "btn": "Rezervišite",
    "cards": [
      {
        "title": "Soho Paradise",
        "rating": "4.9",
        "locationText": "Ibiza, Španija",
        "pricingText": "USD 50/dan",
        "description": "fantastičan pogled na more"
      },
      {
        "title": "Hotel Baja",
        "rating": "5.0",
        "locationText": "Palo Alto, CA",
        "pricingText": "USD 19/dan",
        "description": "najbolje ocenjen smeštaj"
      },
      {
        "title": "Hudak Homes",
        "rating": "4.5",
        "locationText": "Arizoa, RAK",
        "pricingText": "USD 99/dan",
        "description": "cela vila za one sa dubokim džepom"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wyatt Residency",
        "rating": "4.8",
        "locationText": "Rim, Italija",
        "pricingText": "USD 39/dan",
        "description": "sakriven dragulj u srcu Rima"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Thanks :)
P.S. I am using tailwind css in my project but i have deleted styling to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use [`t.raw()`](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/messages#raw-messages) to get the raw data from your translations.

So you could `t.raw("cards")` and get the array of cards.

```js
export default function CardSlider() {
  const t = useTranslations("Popular Apartments");

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      ...
        <Slider ref={setSliderRef} {...sliderSettings}>
          {t.raw("cards").map((card, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              ...
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```